# program error Java programs in Visual code java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

[check here out to see what I actually did and what I doesn't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhlkY.png)
please help me figure out how to remove this address part

```
PS D:\Local disk\LABS\Javaprog\Test>  & 'c:\Users\yagra\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.36.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'D:\Local disk\LABS\Javaprog\Test\bin' 'HelloWorld'
Hello, World!
```

It's giving right output but I don't want that message

Comment: It seems as if you are trying to input 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe' as the second argument to the `cd` call. And that does not match any parameter that `cd` accepts. The whole command looks wrong. Did you miss an `&`?

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't able to elaborate my problem correctly check out the image link it will help u understand better @Seelenvirtuose